# Blank List, Return False

Tags: python, list, return

I'm looking to write a function definition named has_evens that takes in sequence of numbers and returns True if there are any even numbers in the sequence and returns False otherwise.

My code is correct, except when it receives something empty, like "([])". I need to account for that. Here's my code:

```
def has_evens(s):
    for num in s:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return True
        elif num % 2 != 0:
            return False
        if ([]):
            return False
```

The final part is a desperate attempt to account for blank lists. More formally, it needs to pass this assertion:

```
assert has_evens([]) == False
```

Answer (score 3):

You should only return `True` when an even is found:

```
def has_evens(s):
    for num in s:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Python has an `any` function to make this simpler:

```
def has_evens(s):
    return any(num % 2 == 0 for num in s)
```

Comment: I didn't know about the ```any``` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I just needed to un-indent my lines

```
def has_evens(s):
    for num in s:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return True
     else:
         return False
```

Comment: You didn't just un-indent some lines; you also removed the problematic early return when `num %2 != 0`.